# Can I set boolean in sublclass that is inherited from super?

Tags: java

I have a parent class of "Gift" and a bunch of subclasses that extend it. I would like the "warranty" boolean to be true for some and false for others.
I have updated the code to reflect...updates.

It now seems like "Gift" is being implemented, but I am getting an error stating that it is not.

```
public class CustomerGifts {

    public static void giveGift() {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] crowd = new int[100];

        for (int person : crowd) {

            int prize = (int)(Math.random() * 11);

            if(prize >= 0 && prize <= 3) {
                System.out.println("Computer");
                Computer computer = new Computer(true);
                computer.hasWarranty();
            } else if(prize >= 4 && prize <=7) {
                System.out.print("Entertainment");
            } else if (prize >= 8 && prize <= 10) {
                System.out.print("Office");
            }

            System.out.println(prize);
        }

    }

}

class Customer {
    int returns;
}

interface Gift {
    boolean hasWarranty(boolean arg);
}

class Computer implements Gift {
    boolean processor = true;
    boolean warranty;

    Computer(boolean returnable) {
        this.warranty = returnable;
    }

    boolean hasWarranty() {
        return this.warranty;
    }
}
```

Comment: so maybe set it in your constrcutors.

Comment: I am sorry that my comment was of zero help.

Comment: Is `warranty` only depending on the type of gift, or could you still have a Computer without warranty? If it only depends on the type, you should make an abstract method `public abstract boolean isWarranty();` in `Gift` and override it in the subclasses like Computer: `@Override public boolean isWarranty() { return true; }`

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Thank you. That sounds more like what I am looking for. I will give that a try.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Extending on @ErwinBolwidt's comment: you might want to consider making `Gift` an interface rather than a class. Then `isWarranty` could be a method that needs to be implemented. It could even have a default implementation of returning a default value.

Comment: @sprinter  I updated the code but I am not getting a complaint that the "Gift.hasWarranty()" is not being implemented.

Comment: I'll give an example in an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you define `Gift` as an `interface` that is implemented in your classes. Something like:

```
interface Gift {
    boolean hasWarranty();
}

class Computer implements Gift {
    private boolean warranty;

    @Override
    public boolean hasWarranty() {
        return warranty;
    }
}

class GreetingCard implements Gift {
    @Override
    public boolean hasWarranty() {
        return false;
    }
}
```